# Ubuntu disappeared after upgrade!

Tags: boot, 12.10

I just wanted to upgrade my 12.04 LTS version to 12.10. After the upgrade and restarting I encounter just a black page with no messages and nothing! Does anyone have an idea about the reasons of this problem and how to repair it?

Comment: why on earth did you upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10? Why didn't you upgrade to 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Can you open a Console? (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

If yes, login and enter the following command to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If not, try to recover to 12.04 and try to upgrade by using a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) where you enter the following line:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq xorg
```

Comment: Dear Korkel, i am in terminal, but typing the above command answers that the "xorg"packet has been disabled or something like that... (i am translating this from german..). thanks for helping

Comment: Try to rebuild the broken packages using the following command in a terinal `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Updated the answer, try that.

Comment: with the last commando line: sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq xorg, i get: dpkg: failure: unknown option --remove-force . is it not better to install 14.04 from an usb-stick? (sudo apt-get -f install doesnt find this "xorg" either)

Comment: Yes that is the best way then.

Answer (score -1):

It is the black screen of death, use boot repair disk to set boot parementers to nomodeset. If you don't no how just Google "fix Ubuntu black screen of death". Please vote up if this helps

Comment: If you don't know how to help, don't post pleas.

Comment: @Korkel i do know what i was talking about because i have experience in sorting out the black screen of death

Comment: Perhaps you could put that experience to good use and provide a more detailed description.